# Renaming lines in a document using unix commands (Bash)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I have a txt document that is a list of items. Each line is a different name/title. But for this example I will stick to one name.

For example:

```
font0.tff
font1.tff
font2.tff
font3.tff
font4.tff
```

I would like to programmatically change the file to the following, placing each line between `<item></item>` tags:

```
<item>font0.ttf</item>
<item>font1.ttf</item>
<item>font2.ttf</item>
<item>font3.ttf</item>
<item>font4.ttf</item>
```

Comment: Seems like a trivial `sed` command. What problem are you having?

Comment: Did you really mean that they should all become `font.1`, not keep the original font number?

Comment: No they shouldn't. The files have numerous names. Its that I need to take that name and place it in between that tag. I don't want to change the original name.

Comment: So now you want to change the extensions from `tff` to `ttf`? Or is that another typo?

Comment: Do you actually want the `font0.ttf ->` part in the output file? Or was that just your way of showing what the renaming should be?

Comment: The tff to ttf is a typo. I've been up all night so sorry for silly mistakes. I just want to take each list element and place them between the tags.

Answer (score 5):

using `sed`:

```
sed 's#font\.\(.*\)#font\1.ttf -> <item>font.1</item>#' infile > outfile
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am not familiar with sed. But I know this will work. If I want to disregard the file name and extension, how could I modify your code to do so?

Comment: If you expect to be doing any amount of shell scripting, you should become familiar with sed. I'm not sure what you mean by disregarding the filename and extension. Could you update the example in the question to show what you mean?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the & character in sed to reference the matched pattern. I'm using @ to delimit the regex so I don't have to escape the / in `</item>`:

```
sed 's@.*@& -> <item>&</item>@' input.txt
```

Comment: @Randolphg if you just want the renamed item, use `sed 's@.*@<item>&</item>@' input.txt`

Comment: doesn't seem to change the text in the file. terminal shows that something is happening, but when I open the file its still the same text there.

Comment: @Randolphg If you want to change the file then use sed's `-i` option like `sed -i .....`. Only do this after you have verified that the command is correct though

Answer (score 4):

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed 's#.*#<item>&</item>#g' test.txt
<item>font0.tff</item>
<item>font1.tff</item>
<item>font2.tff</item>
<item>font3.tff</item>
<item>font4.tff</item>
```

which is shorthand for

```
$ sed 's#\(.*\)#<item>\1</item>#g' test.txt
```

Alternatively, using `awk`:

```
$ awk '$0="<item>"$0"</item>"' test.txt
<item>font0.tff</item>
<item>font1.tff</item>
<item>font2.tff</item>
<item>font3.tff</item>
<item>font4.tff</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably awk is the simpler/faster way.

If you do not need to change the extension

```
awk '{print "<item>"$0"</item>"}' Test.txt  > NewFile.txt
```

If you need to change the extension from `.tff` to `.ttf` the following line is easy to remember

```
awk '{print "<item>"$0"</item>"}' Test.txt | sed s/".tff"/".ttf"/g  > NewFile.txt
```